# How to strong sign an .exe file in .NET?

Tags: asp.net, dll, exe, sign, strongname

how to properly sign an `.exe` with a pfx certificate installed on machine.

I have a `pfx` certificate by the name "Services installed. I tried signing the `exe` with this command.

```
.\sn.exe -Rc "%Directory%\File.exe" "Services" >> "%LogPath%"
```

It gave no errors. But when I ran this exe file, it started throwing error for the internal project dll(ExtraFile.dll), which is referenced inside File.exe project.
[image]

This dll I am already signing before signing the File.exe file. So the signing steps are as follow.

```
.\sn.exe -Rc "%Directory%\ExtraFile.dll" "Services" >> "%LogPath%"
.\sn.exe -Rc "%Directory%\File.exe" "Services" >> "%LogPath%"
```

Please note that ExtraFile.dll is referenced under File.exe project.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a cryptographic key pair using the Strong Name tool (Sn.exe) and assigning that key pair to the assembly using either a command-line compiler or the Assembly Linker (Al.exe). The Windows SDK provides both Sn.exe and Al.exe.

Comment: Please read my question again. I am doing all those steps.